# How to get first day of week when i know week number in ISO 8601

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, iso8601

I know year and week number for example

```
year = 2016
week = 1
```

how to get **first day of week** from this according to **ISO 8601** ?

I have in table `datetime2[0]` datetype which generate default value `2015-12-28` but first day of the week should be `2016-01-04`

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any date, this SQL will return the ISO-week: `SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date)`. Below is an ugly (but quite effective) one-liner to calculate the first date of that ISO-week:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2012-09-16'
SELECT (
    CASE DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @date) 
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-6,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-6,@date)
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-5,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-5,@date)
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-4,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-4,@date)
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-3,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-3,@date)
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-2,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,@date)
        WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-1,@date)) THEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,@date)
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY,0,@date)
    END
) FirstDayOfISOWeek
```

Now, it's not my prettiest work, but it works by trial and error - testing for how many days ago the ISO-week is still the same, then returning that day.

Comment: thank you, that is very nice, I did not know that DATEPART has ISO_WEEK parameter. I tried it and it seems it works :-) Also I updated my answer, because microsoft already has bult in class in .NET for this, called `ISOWeek`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do with business data is to store it in tables. And ISO weeks are business data. If you had a table that looked like this

```
calendar_date   iso_year    iso_week
--
2016-01-01      2015        53
2016-01-02      2015        53
2016-01-03      2015        53
2016-01-04      2016        1
2016-01-05      2016        1
2016-01-06      2016        1
2016-01-07      2016        1
```

then answering the question "Whats the first date of ISO week 1 in 2016?" simplifies to this.

```
select min(calendar_date) 
from calendar
where iso_year = 2016;
  and iso_week = 1;
```

Here's how to create such a table. (Not rigorously tested.)

```
create table calendar (
  calendar_date date primary key,
  iso_year integer not null,
  iso_week integer not null,
  check (iso_week = datepart(iso_week, calendar_date)),
  check (iso_year = year(dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, calendar_date) / 7, 3)))
);
```

This code will populate it.

```
declare @start_date date;
select @start_date = '2016-01-01';
declare @end_date date;
select @end_date = '2050-12-31';

declare @next_date date;
select @next_date = (select coalesce(max(calendar_date), @start_date) from calendar);

while @next_date <= @end_date 
begin
    begin transaction;
    insert into calendar values (@next_date , year(dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, @next_date) / 7, 3)), datepart(iso_week, @next_date));
    commit;
    select @next_date = dateadd(d, 1, @next_date);
end
```

Control privileges carefully. Very few people should have insert, update, or delete privileges.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I remember that I solved it via CLR procedure and with C# code, I will post it here, but this pure SQL seems good!

Answer (score 0):

CLR function is also a possibility

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Globalization;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static DateTime fnFirstDateOfWeekISO8601(int year, int weekOfYear)
    {
        DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;

        DateTime firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

        var weekNum = weekOfYear;
        if (firstWeek <= 1)
        {
            weekNum -= 1;
        }
        var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);
        return result.AddDays(-3);
    }
}
```

**#update 2020-09-13**

Microsoft has already class for this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek?view=netcore-3.1
so the CLR function might look like more simple

```
using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
    using System.Globalization;
    
    public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
        public static DateTime fnFirstDateOfWeekISO8601(int year, int weekOfYear)
        {
           return System.Globalization.ISOWeek.ToDateTime(year, weekOfYear, DayOfWeek.Monday); 
        }
    }
```